# $x^2 + 3xy + y^2 = n$ Diophantine Equation

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, quadratic-forms, pell-type-equations

I was wondering if someone could direct me towards information regarding the $x^2 + 3xy +y^2 = n$ diophantine equation. Additionally, is there anything about the general case of these diophantine equations in the form $x^{2k} + 3x^ky^k + y^{2k} = n$?

Comment: That's $(2x+3y)^2-5y^2=4n$, so a generalised Pell equation.

Comment: While I was looking for solutions to the generalized Pell equation, I encountered solutions to equations such as $x^2 - Dy^2 = \pm 4$ if $D \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$. The solutions to this diophantine equation are given by: $\frac{x+y\sqrt{5}}{2} = \pm \left( \frac{x_0 + y_0 \sqrt{D}}{2} \right)^k$. How can this be extrapolated to solve the case where $x^2 - Dy^2 = 4n$?

Comment: Here's a well known quadratic diophantine equation solver.
https://www.alpertron.com.ar/QUAD.HTM

Comment: Change variables so that $y=0\implies u=0$ and $x=0\implies t=u$, thus $y=u, x=t-u$. Then $x^2+3xy+y^2=(t-u)^2+3(t-u)u+u^2$ $=t^2 -2tu +u^2 +3tu -3u^2 +u^2$ $=t^2 +tu -u^2$.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend Conways's topograph method.  Here is the diagram for $u^2 + uv - v^2,$ which is "equivalent" to your form, which is reduced in Zagier's style.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]