# Integer solutions to the equation $y^2\pm3xy+x^2=\ell$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I would like to know if the number of integer points on curves of the form $$y^2\pm3xy+x^2=\ell$$ where $\ell$ is a prime number, is finite or not. Also, is there a name for such equation ?
Thank you !

EDIT : I require solutions $x,y$ to be positive, hence it is immediate that $y^2+3xy+x^2=\ell$ has finitely many solutions.

Answer (score 4):

Assume either $x$ or $y$ is even. WLOG $x=2z$. So $y^2-6yz+4z^2=\ell$. This means $(y-3z)^2-5z^2=\ell$. Denote $y-3z=t$. We have $t^2-5z^2=\ell$. It is a generalized Pell equation.  If it has a solution, it has infinitely many solutions, see [this](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/ugradnumthy/pelleqn2.pdf) text by K. Conrad, Section 3. Or [this](http://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/154Page/handouts/genpell.pdf) text by, I believe, his brother. See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3051635/x2-3xy-y2-n-diophantine-equation) question.

Answer (score 2):

Every indefinite binary quadratic form, integer coefficients and discriminant positive but not a square, has an infinite automorphism group. In the special case of your $x^2 - 3 xy + y^2,$ this can be described with what the contests call "Vieta Jumping." Suppose you have a solution, with integers $x > y > 0,$ to
$$  x^2 - 3xy + y^2 = \ell  $$
You get an infinite sequence of solutions, increasing in the first entry, by repeatedly applying
$$  (x,y)  \mapsto (3x-y,x)  $$
Note that $x>y>0$ tells us $x-y > 0,$ $2x-y > x,$ indeed $3x-y > 2x.$ So the first number keeps growing, and both stay positive.

For example, to represent the prime $5$ by $x^2 - 3xy + y^2,$ we get a sequence of solutions
$$  (4,1) \mapsto (11,4)  \mapsto (29,11) 
 \mapsto (76,29)  \mapsto (199,76)
 \mapsto (521,199)  \mapsto \cdots $$

Answer (score 1):

$y^2\pm3xy+x^2=\ell\implies (2 y \pm 3 x)^2 - 5 x^2 = 4 \ell$

This Pell equation with infinite set integer solutions for $\ell$=`5, 11, 19, 29, 31, 41, 59, 61, 71, 79, 89, 101, 109, 131, 139, 149, 151, 179, 181, 191, 199, ...`, and no solutions for others $\ell$. But positive solutions are only for $y^2-3xy+x^2=\ell$.